# Click a link to run MySQL query for that specific value in the link (php)

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I had a hard time to find a solution for this, most of the questions asked were to click a button to run a query.

What I have is a list of db table names in a HTML table. I need them to be in hyperlink format, once I click a table name it should send the name of the table to a php file and run mysql query to get all the attributes of the table.

What's the best way to do this? thanks for all suggestions in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with _all the attributes of the table_?

Answer (score 0):

huh? how about phpmyadmin if you want to use querying

but if you like to build your own SQL query tool then learn this things:

**List database:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php

**List Tables:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

**and lastly List Fields**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php

---

**ADDING THE AMBIGUOUS REQUEST OF Q-Starter.**

**@example:index.php**

```
<form method="get" action="query.php">
    <label>Statement: </label><input type="text" name="sqlState"/>
</form>
```

**@example:query.php**

```
<?php
    $sqlState = $_GET['sqlState'];
    $result = mysql_query($sqlState);
    echo $result;
?>
```

This is bad programming codes but if you really want to explore then go and try this codes, just use this on your own, this might damaged your DATABASE if other users tries to use the so called **"SQL INJECTION"**.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin, but I am building a webpage to interact with users, to get string and run mysql query.

Comment: so you want to have a FORM wherein the user could input SQL STATEMENTS?
Doing this might damage your database, unless your website is for DATABASE management tool that they can create their own DATABASE and TABLES...but if you're just letting them to do SQL STATEMENTS then your DATABASE might be the problems.